# Is there a way to convert tiff image to Base64 without loading complete file into memory

Tags: java, image, base64, tiff, java-io

I've a very large image file in TIFF format (upto 100MB), I need to convert this image into Base64 and then write to XML file. I am wondering if there is a way to stream read image file, convert it into Base64 and write to XML using Java IO streams without loading full file into memory all at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just read small segments of the image file with a stream, convert to base 64, and output to xml?  Converting to base64 shouldn't require reading the entire file.

Edit:

Standard Java API does not include a Base64 encoder.
Try [Apache Commons Base64InputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html).

Comment: Thats what i am exactly looking for. Can you please share code sample of how will you read segment of file in stream and convert to base64. The way I know is require reading file as a whole, convert to byte[] and then to base64 encoded string

Comment: I guess base64encoder is missing from basic java api.  I'd try Apache commons.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html

Comment: Ensure you read data chuncks in multiple of 3 bytes, otherwise you might face problems with the padding.